# Railsでcarriewaveを使用して画像をアップロードする

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Ruby on Rails4でアプリ開発しています。

今回、画像アップロード機能を実装するためcarriewaveを導入しました。

画像アップロードはブログ機能につけて、ブログ記事と画像(任意)で投稿できるようにしました。

投稿の際はnew→confirm→cretaeと遷移して確認画面を経由して投稿できるようにしました。

**問題点**
画像は任意で登録できるようにしたいのですが、画像をアップロードしない場合にエラーになってしまいます。

```
# エラーメッセージ
CarrierWave::InvalidParameter at /topics
invalid cache id
```

画像をアップロードする際は正常に動きます。

現在コードはこのように記述しています。

`_form.html.erb`

```
#省略
  <%= f.label :アップロード写真 %>
  <%= f.file_field :photo %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :photo_cache %>
#省略
```

`confirm.html.erb`

```
#省略
  <%= image_tag (@topic.photo.url) if @topic.photo.present? %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :"cache[photo]", @topic.photo.cache_name %>
#省略
```

`topics_controller`

```
class TopicsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    if params[:back]
      @topic = Topic.new(topics_params)
    else
      @topic = Topic.new
    end
  end

  def create
    @topic = Topic.new(topics_params)
    @topic.photo.retrieve_from_cache! params[:cache][:photo]
    @topic.save!
    @topic.user_id = current_user.id

    respond_to do |format|
     if @topic.save
      format.html { redirect_to @topic, notice: '投稿しました！' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @topic }
     else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @topic.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
     end
    end
  end


  def confirm
    @topic = Topic.new(topics_params)
    render :new if @topic.invalid?
  end

# 一部省略


  private
    def topics_params
      params.require(:topic).permit(:title, :content, :photo_cache, :photo, :tag_list)
    end

    def set_topic
      @topic = Topic.find(params[:id])
    end
end
```

どのように修正すればいいかご教授お願いします。

・追記
エラー時のログはこのようになっています。

```
Started POST "/topics" for ::1 at 2017-04-09 14:16:58 +0900
Processing by TopicsController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"3YIrH2Y/s/011pnlah8L6LFvGGdDzUmIFhxw28WvHDHG04r8DLH4taSgS+WIhUPAFapQrDZP1YzWcGWQgXv95Q==", "topic"=>{"title"=>"hoge", "content"=>"hoge", "tag_list"=>"huga"}, "cache"=>{"photo"=>""}, "commit"=>"投稿する"}
User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 3]]
(0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "notifications" WHERE "notifications"."user_id" = $1 AND "notifications"."read" = $2  [["user_id", 3], ["read", "f"]]
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 7ms (ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)

CarrierWave::InvalidParameter - invalid cache id:
 carrierwave (1.0.0) lib/carrierwave/uploader/cache.rb:193:in `cache_id='
 carrierwave (1.0.0) lib/carrierwave/uploader/cache.rb:158:in `block in retrieve_from_cache!'
 carrierwave (1.0.0) lib/carrierwave/uploader/callbacks.rb:15:in `with_callbacks'
 carrierwave (1.0.0) lib/carrierwave/uploader/cache.rb:157:in `retrieve_from_cache!'
 app/controllers/topics_controller.rb:31:in `create'
 actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
 ・・・
  # 省略
```

Comment: エラー時のrailsのログの内容はわかりますか？ 具体的なエラー内容が分かると答えやすくなるかもしれません。

Comment: エラー時のログを追記致しました。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/71722

Answer (score 0):

下記のような形で画像がある時だけ処理を加えてやるのではダメなのでしょうか？

`@topic.photo.retrieve_from_cache! params[:cache][:photo] if params[:cache][:photo].present?`